# virtualhost document root access previous folder

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

How to access previous folder via index.html that not included in virtualhost document root.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/banking/personal-banking
        ServerName   www.zbux.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.zbux.com-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.zbux.com-ssl_access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/zbux_com.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/zbux_com.ca-bundle
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/zbux.com.key 
</VirtualHost>
```

where personal-banking folder contain index.html and that file need to access folder bak in banking folder.

Comment: HTML files are static and don't *"access"* anything. Could you please try to clarify more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alias to in your virtualhost.
add below line to your virtualhost.

> alias /parentdir /var/www/banking/

Now directories under "banking" folder can accessible using links as below

```
http://www.zbux.com/parentdir/bak
http://www.zbux.com/parentdir/bak/1.html
```

Comment: DocumentRoot /var/www/banking/personal-banking
        ServerName   www.zbux.com  
  Alias /var/www/banking /var/www/banking/personal-banking is not working

Comment: https://zbux.com/

Answer (score 0):

Followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411978/how-to-redirect-user-from-php-file-back-to-index-html-on-dreamhost

where I have write an index.html file and upload it in /banking folder.